# Using C# Record, can I accept a parameter of type A, but return a value of type B?

Tags: c#, .net-core, record

I am using .net Core C#
I am looking to create a record with a single value of type "Severity". Severity is an Enum value. However, when returning the value of Severity within a record, I would like it to return a string (Severity.ToString()). Is this possible?

```
public record BadRequestResponse(Severity Severity);
```

usage

Comment: yes, this is possible. did you try it?

Comment: What do you mean by "However, when returning the value of Severity within a record"? If you want a property type of String (and *no* property of type Severity) but a constructor parameter of type Severity, I suspect that requires an explicit constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property inside the record

```cs
public record BadRequestResponse(Severity Severity)
{
    public string SeverityString => Severity.ToString();
}
```

Note that a record is really just a class with some members created automatically. You can expand it by replacing the `;` with `{  }` and add your own members.

Or override `ToString` if returning the severity for `ToString()` is acceptable

```cs
public record BadRequestResponse(Severity Severity)
{
    public override string ToString() => Severity.ToString();
}
```